# Pyramid structure using <dd>

Tags: html, css

I tried `display:inline-block` but then the `position: relative` won't work anymore and it is mandatory to use `<div>` for these boxes no `<div>`, `<span>` etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. **Note**, questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the _**shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tile-row{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tile{
     width:32%;
     float: left;
     height: 100px;
     background: #456789;
     margin-left:10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
       .tile-row > div:nth-of-type(1)
        {
            float: none;
            margin: 10px 100px;

        }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
        .tile-row > div:nth-of-type(1){
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        .tile{
            float:none;
            background: #333333;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

}
```

```html
<div class='tile-row'>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
</div>
```

Check this example once.

Comment: Good example and can you please tell if i want to make two side arrows between them.Can use another div for each arrow.Look at the link for proper idea.                                  https://www.screencast.com/t/oRmLr8SL

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: yes tried a different approach.First, i put left arrow entity in div and then using "before" I make a right arrow using border property then combined them using position.

Comment: please tell how to make arrows